# What does this integration notation mean?

Tags: notation, contour-integration

I cannot figure out how to interpret the old integration marking below:

[image: Old Riemannian integral]

This sample is taken from *On Riemann's Letters on Analytical Numerical Theory*. Is it legal to write it like this:

[image: Modern Riemannian integral]

Hope somebody can help me:) Thank you for advance.

Comment: It's explained right under the formula.

Comment: It's an integral along a path as described. The questions I'd have is which axis ($x$ or $y$) is being referred to, and does the bisector have a slope of $-1$. If the slope is $-1$ then the question of which axis goes away, because the line will intersect both axis between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : yes, it has an explanation, but that doesn't help me either. To me, an integral, which extends from +infinity to +infinity looks like a defined integral with lower limit +infinity and upper limit +infinity, which is a zero.

Comment: @Xpw : I don't know about axis, but the integral is a "whole function", whatever it means. I even don't know, what "bisector" means in mathematics.

Comment: Yes, that part of the description is rather bad. What it means is that with $x(t) = c + t\cdot (-1+i)$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$, where $0 < c < 1$, one looks at the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(x(t))\cdot x'(t)\,dt,$$ where $F(x) = \dfrac{e^{-\pi ix^2 + 2\pi iux}}{e^{\pi i x} - e^{-\pi ix}}$.

Comment: Entire function, not "whole". "Ganz" has several translations, and here "entire" is the used term. An entire function is a function that is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$ (on the entire plane).

Comment: A bisector is an entity that cuts/splits something in two equal parts. Here, what is meant is the line $\{ x + iy : y = -x\}$, which cuts the second and fourth quadrant each into two equal parts.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : Daniel, thank you so much!!